# How to speed up Docker under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: performance, docker, optimization

I think my containers in the docker is too slow.

Start of 8 containers takes about 10-15 mins.
My colleagues use docker under Mac and for the same set of containers it takes a few minutes (2-3 mins) to start.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: I don't have this issue, please give more details. Which images or do you build it on start?  what command you use to start it ... Did you already download all dependencies....

Comment: I think I've found the source of issue. By some weird reason I used `aufs` as storage driver instead of `overlay2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with type of storage driver it was `aufs` instead of `overlay2`.
After I changed docker configuration and restarted docker it started to work faster